# Javascript not working when I change to Google JQuery Libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Previously I am using JQuery library from here
http://jquery.com/download/

```
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
```

I try to include the following code, it work perfectly.

Javascript

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
                function loading_show(){
                    $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
                }
                function loading_hide(){
                    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
                }                
                function loadData(page){
                    loading_show();                    
                    $.ajax
                    ({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "listcontact.php",
                        data: "page="+page,
                        success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $("#con").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                            {
                                loading_hide();
                                $("#con").html(msg);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
                $('#con .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                    var page = $(this).attr('p');
                    loadData(page);

                });           
                $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                    var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                    var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                    if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                        loadData(page);
                    }else{
                        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                        $('.goto').val("").focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                });
            });
```

HTML

```
  <div id="con">
            <div class="data"></div>
            <div class="pagination"></div>
        </div>
```

And Then I try to use JQuery js from Google instead from JQuery.com
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
```

The Tab menu still can work, however I cannot get any data from listcontact.php

How can I make it work in Google JQuery?

this is all my script tag

```
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is my tab menu

```
      <nav>

          <div id="tabs">

           <ul>
             <li><b><a href="#tabs-1">More Details</a></b></li>
              <li><b><a href="#tabs-2">Contact</a></b></li>
              <li><b><a href="#tabs-3">Files</a></b></li>
              <li><b><a href="#tabs-4">Sales pipeLine</a></b></li>
              <li><b><a href="#tabs-5">Call report</a></b></li>
          </ul>

                   <div id="tabs-1">
            <?php //include('viewdetail.php') ;?>     

          </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">
 <?php 
 if( $view == 0)
 {
include('contact.php');
 }
 else
 {
  include('newcontact.php') ;
 }

  ?>
        </div>
            <div id="tabs-3">
 <?php //include('filemanagement.php') ;?>
  </div>
         <div id="tabs-4">

         Under Development

  </div>
            <div id="tabs-5">
           <?php //include('callReport.php') ;?>   


  </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

The code is inside my contact page, when I try to include it inside my tab

Comment: You need to check the change logs for those versions. Quite a bit has changed.

Comment: Also....how are you including that ajax.googleapis.com file?  Show the code for that, like the actual <script> tag stuff

Comment: This `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js` is a migration tool. This `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js` is a jQuery library. Which are you loading? Can you show the `<script>` tags you are actually using in your page?

Comment: `live` is removed now. You need to change it to `on`. Rest looks fine to me.

Comment: I m loading this ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Have you done my suggested changes???  You need to load jquery BEFORE, you load the UI....see below, and fix, and tell me if it works now

Comment: look at console and see what errors you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing locally? Or remotely?

If you are local....you usually have to attach http:// to the google apis

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If not then just....

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Should work...

This should also be replaced...from **.live()** to **.on()** as .live() is now deprecated

```
 $('body').on('click','#go_btn', function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                }else{
```

**EDIT / UPDATE**

You posted this...

```
 <script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Change to this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The jquery needs to be above the jquery-ui, as the ui has a dependancy on Jquery, and you can remove v1.9 no sense in loading jquery twice

EDIT 3

I would change this...you don't need that ajaxComplete call, since the success function is doing that anyway...

```
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "listcontact.php",
                    data: {page: page},
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#con").html(msg);

                    }
                });
```

And you made sure to change both your live()'s???

You had two, the other one should look like this...

```
$('body').on('click','#con .pagination li.active' function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);
            });
```

Comment: if I use <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script> , my whole tab menu won't appear, I cant add the HTTP://

Comment: You also need two dashes infront of the ajax.googlepais.com //  in your code you posted above...and the jquery should go above the jquery-ui, and you can remove the v 1.9

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Jquery has to come BEFORE UI, as I have posted above...just copy my two lines as I have them, and replace in your code....should work

Comment: I change to your JQuery, and I also change live to on, but still can't load anything from loaddata

Comment: See new additions to my answer

Comment: Correct...sorry that was a typo on my part

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `live` might not work with the latest version

Replace

```
.live('click'
```

with

```
.on('click'
```

If there are any dynamically added elements on the page replace your events with this syntax

```
$(staticContainer).on('click', 'selector'  function(){
```

Where **staticContainer** is the closest static ancestor of the element.

**selector** is the element to which you want to attach the event.

Comment: You may want to add that you'll need to use event delegation. `.on` isn't a drop-in replacement for `.live`.

Comment: @Blender.. I don't see the OP appending element to the `DOM` using Ajax.. So event delegation might not be a issue here

Comment: how to Use the $(staticContainer).on('click', 'selector'  function(){

Comment: @Ryan Ive shown you how to use it in the answer above this one.....do you not read your answers??? Ive provided you everything you need, the .live() change, and how to properly laod your scripts, yet somehow, this question still remains unsettled.....???

Comment: sorry, my I still can't load the data from it

Answer (score 0):

try to include the same version JQuery from google :

Number of version JQuery from google should be equal number of version JQuery from Jquery website

but if you want to use recent version, there are some changes , and you should modify something in your code, see log console for more info about problem and check documentation of JQuery [here](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I had experience with similar issue, it may deal with deprecated functions! **check EACH piece of function, so that deprecated methods are corrected** :) Hope this help you go to somewhere right :)
[deprecated-ajax-or-jquery-command-cause-no-result-returned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174237/deprecated-ajax-or-jquery-command-cause-no-result-returned)
Enjoy!