# Deprecated Ajax Or JQuery Command Cause No Result Returned

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pagination, deprecated

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function loading_show(){
                $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');

            }
            function loading_hide(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');

            }                
            function loadData(page){
                loading_show();    

                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg){
                        $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)//.ajaxComplete is good
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#container").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
                 alert();

            }
            loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
            $('#container .pagination li.active').on('click',function(){//replaced .live with .on
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);

            });           
            $('#go_btn').on('click',function(){//replaced .live with .on
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Above is the pagination code from [The paginatio tutorial here](http://onlinewebapplication.com/pagination-jquery-php-ajax-mysql/). **I try to use jquery 1.9.1 instead of the code piece use 1.4.**
But seem even I changed the deprecated .live to .on, still, no result has been rendered. I can not find any deprecated code among this piece. However, other code in the tutorial are seemingly perfect as well. So I would consider there must be some thing wrong with the javascript & ajax code above.

with the help from KyleK, the modified version (yet still not working) is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function loading_show(){
                $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
            }
            function loading_hide(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
            }                
            function loadData(page){
                loading_show();                    
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "load_data.php",
                    data: {page: page},
                    //ORIGINAL data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#container").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
            $('body').on('click','#container .pagination li.active', function(){
            //ORIGINAL $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);

            });           
            $('body').on('click','#go_btn',function(){
            //ORIGINAL $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be editing your solution into your question.  Add an answer if you would like to contribute an answer that hasn't already been posted that answers your question.

Comment: @Servy You are interesting, so its wrong to answer the question to complete the answer from a great contributor like KyleK, while you are tooth-picking on little tiny bit things? Good job again.

Comment: @It's wrong to edit the answer into the question, yes.  You should post it as an answer if it's contributing sufficient content to warrant being posted, which does appear to be the case here.  You could also consider just commenting on the answers that helped to derive that solution if you feel that the important information can be condensed into a comment.  Again, if you're going to ask people to critique your posts, you shouldn't be surprised if they actually do it, you should be *grateful*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way your data is passed in the ajax...

From...

```
url: "load_data.php",
data: "page="+page,
```

To..

```
url: "load_data.php",
data: {page: page},
```

ANd change this...

```
 $('#container .pagination li.active').on('click',function(){
```

To this...

```
 $('body').on('click','#container .pagination li.active', function(){
```

And same here...

```
 $('#go_btn').on('click',function()
```

To...

```
 $('body').on('click','#go_btn',function()
```

I think I already suggested that the last time I answered this same question yesterday...

Comment: I did not find similar topic, sry if that make you answered twice. Could you refer to the question you did for the previous person? Also,I am still fixing the code according to your suggestions, but seem did not work, still try to figure out why. And liyakat suggested method a bid different than yours on  $('body').on('click','#container .pagination li.active', function(){, he suggest to be on (document), instead of ('body') is that right? Thanks

Comment: document or body....both will work....also I answered this yesterday here....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159352/javascript-not-working-when-i-change-to-google-jquery-libraries/17159380#17159380   You're both using same script I guess??

Comment: Its a pagination script from the link I provided in the bottom of the question http://onlinewebapplication.com/pagination-jquery-php-ajax-mysql/ That might be the case. However, I use the exact change you offered here, still no result returned.

Comment: Well does any of your html actually match any of the selctors???  and what is var page = $(this).attr('p');??  its gotta get the page from somewhere, do you have a li item with attribute p, to get page???

Comment: I think it does not even go that far yet, btw, i do not know why that var page write the way it is now... however, so far I think the main issue is that even the loadData(1); is not even running correctly, since I think, the ajax is not getting the data correctly therefore, loadData(1) is kind invalid function.

Answer (score 1):

here is basic difference between live and on you can check

```
$('selector').live(event, function(){ //do stuff here })
```

and in on

```
$(document).on(event, selector, function(){ //do stuff here })
```

And also you can refer detail [Documentation](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/on-vs-live-review/) to get better idea to convert it

let me know if i can help you more.

Comment: you actually did help in a way and hinted my thought to my final resolution, thanks! :)